# PHP - AWS CloudWatch Logs return tooNewLogEventsStartIndex

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-php-sdk

I'm using `AWS PHP SDK` in order to allow clients application to send batch of Log Events to my central log @ AWS CloudWatch Logs.

Using the PutLogEvents() method i'm pushing a batch of logs to AWS and receive the following response with `tooNewLogEventStartIndex` as rejected reason.

```
object(Guzzle\Service\Resource\Model)#192 (2) {
  ["structure":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["data":protected]=>
  array(2) {
    ["nextSequenceToken"]=>
    string(56) "49557048644494214342955772042233869869420536807120962306"
    ["rejectedLogEventsInfo"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["tooNewLogEventStartIndex"]=>
      int(0)
    }
  }
}
```

I couldn't find any documentation @ AWS explaining what this error means.. Does someone knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this error means that the timestamp on the log event is to far in the future.
I did a mistake in my code and multiply my timestamp in 1000 (to microseconds) which was too much and made the timestamp in valid.